# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Search table with multiple nullable parameters on the same column

Tags: search, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on a search tool where I need to search a table using up to 6 search parameters, the issue is, 5 of the 6 parameters need to search the same column.

I'm searching a temp table that is populated from an `item_category` table, this temp table has 3 columns, `item`, `item_desc` and `cat_desc`. The first search parm is `@Desc` and this parm will search the `item_desc` column, the other 5 parms are `@P1`, `@P2`, `@P3`, `@P4` and `@P5`, all are `nvarchar(40)` types. These `@P#` parms all need to search the `cat_desc` column.

Below is the code to create a temp table with sample data, and my query code that I have so far. I tried to explain each section with comments, and I'll explain below the code what I need it to do.

```
-- Create Temp Tables --
CREATE TABLE #Item_Category_List(
        item        nvarchar(30)
        ,item_desc  nvarchar(40)
        ,cat_desc   nvarchar(40));

-- Populate #Item_Category_List with sample data
INSERT #Item_Category_List(item, item_desc, cat_desc)
VALUES ('2-77132', '2-77132 P1812-24-120', 'Keypad PB Controls W/Variable Speed')
    ,('2-77132', '2-77132 P1812-24-120', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-77132', '2-77132 P1812-24-120', '1 x 3.00HP Motor')
    ,('2-77132', '2-77132 P1812-24-120', 'Light Curtain Option')
    ,('2-77132', '2-77132 P1812-24-120', 'Bin Detection Option')
    ,('2-77132', '2-77132 P1812-24-120', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-77132', '2-77132 P1812-24-120', '480 Volts')
    ,('2-70470', 'CANTILEVER-CRSL-C20243-3912-194', 'Vidir Inventory Control Software')
    ,('2-70470', 'CANTILEVER-CRSL-C20243-3912-194', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-70470', 'CANTILEVER-CRSL-C20243-3912-194', 'SEW Motor')
    ,('2-70470', 'CANTILEVER-CRSL-C20243-3912-194', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-70470', 'CANTILEVER-CRSL-C20243-3912-194', '460 Volts')
    ,('2-77562', 'HT54193-0663-12-RAMP', 'Keypad PB Controls W/Variable Speed')
    ,('2-77562', 'HT54193-0663-12-RAMP', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-77562', 'HT54193-0663-12-RAMP', 'Top Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-77562', 'HT54193-0663-12-RAMP', '2 x 2.00HP Motor')
    ,('2-77562', 'HT54193-0663-12-RAMP', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-77562', 'HT54193-0663-12-RAMP', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-76559', 'R20116-1416-4M 2-HAND CONTROLS', '2 Hand Security Control')
    ,('2-76559', 'R20116-1416-4M 2-HAND CONTROLS', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-76559', 'R20116-1416-4M 2-HAND CONTROLS', '50 Hertz')
    ,('2-76559', 'R20116-1416-4M 2-HAND CONTROLS', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-76559', 'R20116-1416-4M 2-HAND CONTROLS', '1 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-76559', 'R20116-1416-4M 2-HAND CONTROLS', '1 Phase')
    ,('2-76559', 'R20116-1416-4M 2-HAND CONTROLS', '220 Volts')
    ,('2-73432', 'R20116-1614-06', 'PB Controls')
    ,('2-78125', 'R20116-1614-06', 'PB Controls')
    ,('2-74803', 'R20116-1614-06', 'PB Controls Dual W/Selector and Beeper')
    ,('2-78125', 'R20116-1614-06', '50 Hertz')
    ,('2-74803', 'R20116-1614-06', '50 Hertz')
    ,('2-73432', 'R20116-1614-06', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-73432', 'R20116-1614-06', 'Right Side Front and Back Location')
    ,('2-74803', 'R20116-1614-06', 'Right Side Front and Back Location')
    ,('2-78125', 'R20116-1614-06', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-78125', 'R20116-1614-06', '1 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-73432', 'R20116-1614-06', '1 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-74803', 'R20116-1614-06', '1 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-74803', 'R20116-1614-06', 'Pigtail, Top Option')
    ,('2-74803', 'R20116-1614-06', '1 Phase')
    ,('2-78125', 'R20116-1614-06', '1 Phase')
    ,('2-73432', 'R20116-1614-06', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-74803', 'R20116-1614-06', '110 Volts')
    ,('2-78125', 'R20116-1614-06', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-73432', 'R20116-1614-06', '480 Volts')
    ,('2-76582', 'R20116-1614-09', 'PB Controls')
    ,('2-76582', 'R20116-1614-09', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-76582', 'R20116-1614-09', 'Right Side Front and Back Location')
    ,('2-76582', 'R20116-1614-09', '2 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-76582', 'R20116-1614-09', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-76582', 'R20116-1614-09', '220 Volts')
    ,('2-59350', 'R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-59350', 'R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-59350', 'R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-59350', 'R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS', '1 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-59350', 'R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-59350', 'R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS', '220 Volts')
    ,('2-77592', 'R20158-2214-06', 'PB Controls Dual W/Selector and Beeper')
    ,('2-77592', 'R20158-2214-06', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-77592', 'R20158-2214-06', 'Right Side Front and Back Location')
    ,('2-77592', 'R20158-2214-06', '2 x 1.00HP Motor')
    ,('2-77592', 'R20158-2214-06', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-77592', 'R20158-2214-06', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-48924', 'R20179-2514-12', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-48924', 'R20179-2514-12', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-48924', 'R20179-2514-12', 'Right Side Front and Back Location')
    ,('2-48924', 'R20179-2514-12', '1 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-48924', 'R20179-2514-12', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-48924', 'R20179-2514-12', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-70697', 'R20228-3214-06', 'PB Controls')
    ,('2-70697', 'R20228-3214-06', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-70697', 'R20228-3214-06', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-70697', 'R20228-3214-06', '2 x 1.00HP Motor')
    ,('2-70697', 'R20228-3214-06', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-70697', 'R20228-3214-06', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-76637', 'R24125-1220-06-DC 2-76637', 'PB Controls Dual W/Selector and Beeper')
    ,('2-76637', 'R24125-1220-06-DC 2-76637', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-76637', 'R24125-1220-06-DC 2-76637', 'Top Right Side Front and Back Location')
    ,('2-76637', 'R24125-1220-06-DC 2-76637', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-76637', 'R24125-1220-06-DC 2-76637', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-76965', 'R39150-MS-06-DC 2-76965', 'PB Controls')
    ,('2-76965', 'R39150-MS-06-DC 2-76965', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-76965', 'R39150-MS-06-DC 2-76965', 'Left Side Front and Back Location')
    ,('2-76965', 'R39150-MS-06-DC 2-76965', '2 x 1.00HP Motor')
    ,('2-76965', 'R39150-MS-06-DC 2-76965', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-76965', 'R39150-MS-06-DC 2-76965', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-76909', 'SMALL WIRE CRSL R24159-1422-52', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-76909', 'SMALL WIRE CRSL R24159-1422-52', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-76909', 'SMALL WIRE CRSL R24159-1422-52', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-76909', 'SMALL WIRE CRSL R24159-1422-52', '1 x 1.00HP Motor')
    ,('2-76909', 'SMALL WIRE CRSL R24159-1422-52', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-76909', 'SMALL WIRE CRSL R24159-1422-52', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-54416', 'T39148-0740-15', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-54416', 'T39148-0740-15', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-54416', 'T39148-0740-15', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-54416', 'T39148-0740-15', '2 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-54416', 'T39148-0740-15', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-54416', 'T39148-0740-15', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-56095', 'T39188-0940-15-SV', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-56095', 'T39188-0940-15-SV', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-56095', 'T39188-0940-15-SV', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-56095', 'T39188-0940-15-SV', '2 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-56095', 'T39188-0940-15-SV', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-56095', 'T39188-0940-15-SV', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-53564', 'T45156-0744-15', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-53564', 'T45156-0744-15', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-53564', 'T45156-0744-15', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-53564', 'T45156-0744-15', '2 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-53564', 'T45156-0744-15', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-53564', 'T45156-0744-15', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-65573', 'T45200-0944-15 SV WITH FOLDING GATE', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-65573', 'T45200-0944-15 SV WITH FOLDING GATE', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-65573', 'T45200-0944-15 SV WITH FOLDING GATE', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-65573', 'T45200-0944-15 SV WITH FOLDING GATE', '2 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-65573', 'T45200-0944-15 SV WITH FOLDING GATE', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-65573', 'T45200-0944-15 SV WITH FOLDING GATE', '480 Volts')
    ,('2-76617', 'W39191-1134-06 2-76617', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-76617', 'W39191-1134-06 2-76617', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-76617', 'W39191-1134-06 2-76617', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-76617', 'W39191-1134-06 2-76617', '2 x 1.00HP Motor')
    ,('2-76617', 'W39191-1134-06 2-76617', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-76617', 'W39191-1134-06 2-76617', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-70274', 'W39250-1630-16.5', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-70274', 'W39250-1630-16.5', '50 Hertz')
    ,('2-70274', 'W39250-1630-16.5', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-70274', 'W39250-1630-16.5', '2 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-70274', 'W39250-1630-16.5', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-70274', 'W39250-1630-16.5', '208 Volts')
    ,('2-57285', 'W45243-1240-W-100', 'Keypad PB Controls')
    ,('2-57285', 'W45243-1240-W-100', '60 Hertz')
    ,('2-57285', 'W45243-1240-W-100', 'Right Side Front Location')
    ,('2-57285', 'W45243-1240-W-100', '2 x 1.50HP Motor')
    ,('2-57285', 'W45243-1240-W-100', '3 Phase')
    ,('2-57285', 'W45243-1240-W-100', '208 Volts')
GO

-- Query Parms
DECLARE
    @Desc       nvarchar(40) = NULL
    ,@P1        nvarchar(40) = NULL
    ,@P2        nvarchar(40) = NULL
    ,@P3        nvarchar(40) = NULL
    ,@P4        nvarchar(40) = NULL
    ,@P5        nvarchar(40) = NULL

-- Encase parm values with wildcards, and replace spaces in parm values with wildcards
SELECT
    @Desc = '%' + REPLACE(@Desc, ' ', '%') + '%'
    ,@P1 = '%' + REPLACE(@P1, ' ', '%') + '%'
    ,@P2 = '%' + REPLACE(@P2, ' ', '%') + '%'
    ,@P3 = '%' + REPLACE(@P3, ' ', '%') + '%'
    ,@P4 = '%' + REPLACE(@P4, ' ', '%') + '%'
    ,@P5 = '%' + REPLACE(@P5, ' ', '%') + '%';

-- Create temp table to hold the @P1 - @P5 parms
CREATE TABLE #Parms_List(parms nvarchar(40));

-- Insert @P parms into temp table for use later in INNER JOIN
WITH p (parms)
AS
(
    SELECT @P1
    UNION ALL SELECT @P2
    UNION ALL SELECT @P3
    UNION ALL SELECT @P4
    UNION ALL SELECT @P5    
)
INSERT INTO #Parms_List
SELECT parms FROM p WHERE parms IS NOT NULL

-- Insert all distinct cat_desc if all @P parms are null
IF @P1 IS NULL AND @P2 IS NULL AND @P3 IS NULL AND @P4 IS NULL AND @P5 IS NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Parms_List
    SELECT DISTINCT c.cat_desc
    FROM #Item_Category_List AS c
END

-- Create temp table to hold matching item numbers for @Desc search
CREATE TABLE #Item_Desc_Match_List(item nvarchar(30));

-- Search #Item_Category_List for matching items based on description
-- and insert into #Item_Desc_Match_List for use later in INNER JOIN
IF @Desc IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    -- Insert only matching items from #Item_Category_List
    INSERT INTO #Item_Desc_Match_List
    SELECT DISTINCT t.item
    FROM #Item_Category_List AS t
    WHERE t.item_desc LIKE @Desc
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Insert all items from #Item_Category_List
    INSERT INTO #Item_Desc_Match_List
    SELECT DISTINCT t.item
    FROM #Item_Category_List AS t
END

-- Final Query for matching items
SELECT DISTINCT t.item

FROM #Item_Category_List AS t
INNER JOIN #Item_Desc_Match_List AS i
    ON i.item = t.item
INNER JOIN #Parms_List AS p
    ON t.cat_desc LIKE p.parms

ORDER BY t.item


DROP TABLE #Item_Category_List
DROP TABLE #Parms_List
DROP TABLE #Item_Desc_Match_List
```

Our items can have multiple categories linked to them, the goal with this query is to be able to search for items by up to five different categories, PLUS by the items description, hence the Query Parms, `@P1` to `@P5` and `@Desc`.

For the item description query, I created a temp table `#Item_Desc_Match_List` and I insert my temp date table a list of `DISTINCT` items where the description matches, I then later on in my final query do an `INNER JOIN` to this `#Item_Desc_Match_List` table.

For the category search, my first attempt was just simply to try a where clause like so, `WHERE cat_desc LIKE @P1 OR cat_desc LIKE @P2` and etc... But since any one of the 5 `@P` parms can be null, this didn't work. So my second approach was to put all of my `@P` parms into a temp table, then do an `INNER JOIN` in my final query to my temp data table on the `cat_desc` column. This works, sort of.

Run the above code with the following query parms:

```
@Desc       nvarchar(40) = '1614'
,@P1        nvarchar(40) = NULL
,@P2        nvarchar(40) = NULL
,@P3        nvarchar(40) = NULL
,@P4        nvarchar(40) = NULL
,@P5        nvarchar(40) = NULL
```

You'll get the following results:

```
item
------------------------------
2-59350
2-73432
2-74803
2-76582
2-78125
```

So far, that's correct because all of those items have **1614** in their description. Now change `@P1` to `'60 hertz'` and the results are:

```
item
------------------------------
2-59350
2-73432
2-76582
```

This is also correct, because those three items have **1614** in their description, and they all have the **60 Hertz** category linked. Now change `@P2` to `'220 Volt'` and the results remain unchanged. This is where the problem starts, because only item numbers 2-76582 and 2-59350 have the **220 Volt** category linked.

Change `@P3` to `'1 x 1.50HP'` and the results **SHOULD** decrease to only one, 2-59350 because that item# is the only one where the description is  like `@Desc` and where the linked categories match `@P1`, `@P2` and `@P3`.

I've been spinning my wheels on this report for a few days and I'm not sure how I can get the query to narrow my results as I define more of my `@P` parms, and not increase my results like it currently is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are matching results where **ANY** of the rows match for `cat_desc`, not **ALL** of the rows.

To you the simplest possible example, lets take your second case with no `DISTINCT`:

```
DECLARE  @Desc      nvarchar(40) = '1614'
        ,@P1        nvarchar(40) = '60 hertz'
        ,@P2        nvarchar(40) = '220 Volt'
        ,@P3        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P4        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P5        nvarchar(40) = NULL;

WITH p (param) AS
(
    SELECT  param
    FROM    (VALUES (@p1), (@p2), (@p3), (@p4), (@p5)) p (param)
    WHERE   p.param IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  *
FROM    #Item_Category_List AS t
        INNER JOIN p
            ON t.cat_desc LIKE '%' + p.param + '%'
WHERE   t.item_desc LIKE '%' + @Desc     + '%';
```

You are actually returning all the rows:

```
item    item_desc                   cat_desc    param
--------------------------------------------------------
2-73432 R20116-1614-06              60 Hertz    60 hertz
2-76582 R20116-1614-09              60 Hertz    60 hertz
2-76582 R20116-1614-09              220 Volts   220 Volt
2-59350 R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS   60 Hertz    60 hertz
2-59350 R20116-1614-12-STD-CNTRLS   220 Volts   220 Volt
```

What you really need is to group by `item` and count the rows that match:

```
SELECT  t.item, Matches = COUNT(*) 
FROM    #Item_Category_List AS t
        INNER JOIN p
            ON t.cat_desc LIKE '%' + p.param + '%'
WHERE   t.item_desc LIKE '%' + @Desc + '%'
GROUP BY t.item;
```

Which gives:

```
item    Matches
-------------
2-59350 2
2-73432 1
2-76582 2
```

Then you can limit the results to those items that match the number of parameters (i.e. match on all the parameters supplied not any of them):

```
DECLARE  @Desc      nvarchar(40) = '1614'
        ,@P1        nvarchar(40) = '60 hertz'
        ,@P2        nvarchar(40) = '220 Volt'
        ,@P3        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P4        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P5        nvarchar(40) = NULL;

WITH p (param) AS
(
    SELECT  param
    FROM    (VALUES (@p1), (@p2), (@p3), (@p4), (@p5)) p (param)
    WHERE   p.param IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  t.item
FROM    #Item_Category_List AS t
        INNER JOIN p
            ON t.cat_desc LIKE '%' + p.param + '%'
WHERE   t.item_desc LIKE '%' + @Desc + '%'
GROUP BY t.item
HAVING COUNT(p.Param) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P);
```

Which gives the desired result:

```
item
------------
2-59350
2-76582
```

And finally, for your last case you get a single record (2-59350):

```
DECLARE  @Desc      nvarchar(40) = '1614'
        ,@P1        nvarchar(40) = '60 hertz'
        ,@P2        nvarchar(40) = '220 Volt'
        ,@P3        nvarchar(40) = '1 x 1.50HP'
        ,@P4        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P5        nvarchar(40) = NULL;

WITH p (param) AS
(
    SELECT  param
    FROM    (VALUES (@p1), (@p2), (@p3), (@p4), (@p5)) p (param)
    WHERE   p.param IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  t.item
FROM    #Item_Category_List AS t
        INNER JOIN p
            ON t.cat_desc LIKE '%' + p.param + '%'
WHERE   t.item_desc LIKE '%' + @Desc + '%'
GROUP BY t.item
HAVING COUNT(p.Param) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P);
```

This of course does not account for no parameters being supplied, and no description, so here I would change the inner join to a left join, and add additional logic to the having and where clauses to allow for the parameters not being supplied:

```
DECLARE  @Desc      nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P1        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P2        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P3        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P4        nvarchar(40) = NULL
        ,@P5        nvarchar(40) = NULL;

WITH p (param) AS
(
    SELECT  param
    FROM    (VALUES (@p1), (@p2), (@p3), (@p4), (@p5)) p (param)
    WHERE   p.param IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT  t.item
FROM    #Item_Category_List AS t
        LEFT JOIN p
            ON t.cat_desc LIKE '%' + p.param + '%'
WHERE   t.item_desc LIKE '%' + @Desc + '%'
OR      @Desc IS NULL
GROUP BY t.item
HAVING  COUNT(p.Param) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P)
OR      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P) = 0;
```

This is not likely to perform well, but since all your comparisons are like operations, I don't think you can avoid a full table scan either way.

As an aside, I would consider using a table valued parameter, rather than your 6 parameters:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ListOfString AS TABLE (Value NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

I tend to just create generic types for things like this so they are more reusable, but that is personal preference, if you don't mind having loads of types and are worried about strict data lenth in the table then feel free to make the type more specific.

Then your procedure would be something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchItemCategoryList @Desc NVARCHAR(40), @Params dbo.ListOfString READONLY
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT  t.item
    FROM    dbo.Item_Category_List AS t
            LEFT JOIN @Params AS p
                ON t.cat_desc LIKE '%' + p.Value + '%'
    WHERE   t.item_desc LIKE '%' + @Desc + '%'
    OR      @Desc IS NULL
    GROUP BY t.item
    HAVING  COUNT(p.Value) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Params)
    OR      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Params) = 0;

END
```

And you can call the procedure using something like:

```
-- GET ALL
DECLARE @P dbo.ListOfString;
EXECUTE dbo.SearchItemCategoryList NULL, @p;
GO
-- GET MATCHING JUST DESCRIPTION
DECLARE @P dbo.ListOfString;
EXECUTE dbo.SearchItemCategoryList '1614', @p;
GO
-- GET USING ONE PARAMETER
DECLARE @P dbo.ListOfString;
INSERT @p (Value) VALUES ('60 hertz');
EXECUTE dbo.SearchItemCategoryList '1614', @p;
GO
-- GET USING THREE PARAMETERS
DECLARE @P dbo.ListOfString;
INSERT @p (Value) VALUES ('60 hertz'), ('220 Volt'), ('1 x 1.50HP');
EXECUTE dbo.SearchItemCategoryList '1614', @p;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd539/1)**